# RDD with (key, (key2, value))

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I have an RDD in pyspark of the form (key, other things), where "other things" is a list of fields. I would like to get another RDD that uses a second key from the list of fields. For example, if my initial RDD is:

(User1, 1990 4 2 green...)
(User1, 1990 2 2 green...)
(User2, 1994 3 8 blue...)
(User1, 1987 3 4 blue...)

I would like to get (User1, [(1990, x), (1987, y)]),(User2, (1994 z))

where x, y, z would be an aggregation on the other fields, eg x is the count of how may rows I have with User1 and 1990 (two in this case), and I get a list with one tuple per year.

I am looking at the key value functions from:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html

But don't seem to find anything that will give and aggregation twice: once for user and one for year. My initial attempt was with combineByKey() but I get stuck in getting a list from the values.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following using [`groupby`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#groupBy):

```
# sample rdd
l = [("User1", "1990"), 
     ("User1", "1990"),
     ("User2", "1994"),
     ("User1", "1987") ]

rd = sc.parallelize(l)

# returns a tuples of count of year
def f(l):
    dd = {}
    for i in l:
        if i not in dd:
            dd[i] =1
        else:
            dd[i]+=1
    return list(dd.items())

# using groupby and applying the function on x[1] (which is a list)
rd1 = rd.groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0], f(x[1]))).collect()

[('User1', [('1990', 2), ('1987', 1)]), ('User2', [('1994', 1)])]
```